# Passing authentication credentials with cffile

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, unc, coldfusion-11

Here's the situation:

A CF application needs to upload/write files to locations on different servers. The servers are owned by customers who need to give the application permission to upload/read/update files to them.

To prevent a security leak, each customer will provide a unique username and password that should be passed along with the `<cffile>` function. A UNC folder path will provided by the customer to specify where the files should be uploaded to. All of this will be stored in a database of course. Here's a theoretical example:

```
<cffile action = "upload"  
        fileField = "DocumentUploaded"  
        destination = "\\servername\salesdept\files"  
        accept = "text/html"  
        username = "#rsCustomer.Username#"
        password = "#rsCustomer.Password#" />
```

I understand that ColdFusion passes the username the CF service is using, but that is not going be secure in this situation. Someone could easily go directly to the `destination` field, pass in the CF service credentials and be to access ANY customer's files.

How could I go about trying to achieve a solution to this?

Comment: Could you possibly ftp/sftp the files instead?

Comment: cfhttp post with clientcert? although I've never tried that.

Comment: @JedihomerTownend I don't think I can specify that `cfftp` uses a form field as the file to put to the server? The `filefield` option doesn't exist. It also doesn't have any `accept` option to validate the file being uploaded. I guess I could upload it to the CF server, then FTP it to the customer's server, then delete it from the CF server. However that may still breach security policy because they don't want their files on a 'cloud' server at all.

Comment: *I guess I could upload it to the CF server* Is not the code already doing that? ie cffile action=upload is basically just a rename. The file was already uploaded to a temp directory on the CF.

Comment: @Leigh Yes you're right :)

Comment: So what did you end up doing? :)